# Xcode External Build System Make Package Install

Tags: xcode, makefile, jailbreak, tweak

I created an "External Build System" project in Xcode to run my custom Makefile when run. By default this works fine, but when I want to pass it `-C ~/Desktop/GIFPaper/ package install` so the full shell command equivalent would be:

```
make -C ~/Desktop/GIFPaper/ package install
```

I get this error:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make package requires dpkg-deb.
make: *** [internal-package-check] Error 1
Program ended with exit code: 2
```

The weird thing is that I have dpkg installed and if I open Terminal and change the directory to:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/
```

and the run:

```
make -C ~/Desktop/GIFPaper/ package install
```

everything works fine. So far I have added:

```
-C ~/Desktop/GIFPaper/ package install
```

as arguments to the *Run* scheme. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using a Makefile depending on this file (or a similar rule):

https://github.com/DHowett/theos/blob/master/makefiles/package/deb.mk

It requires that `dpkg-deb` is in the path or will fail with the error message you posted.

You say you installed dpkg, but this doesn't mean an executable called `dpkg-deb` is available to make when invoked from Xcode. Indeed, with your external build system, make is invoked with a restricted PATH. Your solution of installing dpkg-deb and copying to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/` is quite dirty and involves installing the missing binary in Xcode itself, in the first directory of the default PATH.

Alternatively, you can modify the PATH directly from Xcode, by checking "Pass build settings in environment" (this is the default) and adding a PATH build setting. Ideal value would be `${inherited}:/usr/local/bin` or `${inherited}:/opt/local/bin` depending on where `dpkg-deb` is actually installed.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, for anyone with this problem in the future. Download dpkg-deb using `curl http://debmaker-osx.googlecode.com/svn-history/r5/trunk/dpkg-deb > dpkg-deb` then set its permissions as an executable with `chmod +x dpkg-deb` then copy it to the Xcode bin directory with `sudo cp dpkg-deb /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/dpkg-deb`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem.
First of all I installed dpkg with `brew install dpkg` but if I ran `make package install` i received this error

```
dpkg-deb: file `com.mycompany.mytweak.deb' contains ununderstood data member data.tar.xz     , giving up
dpkg: error processing com.mycompany.mytweak.deb (--install):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
```

This because the compress algoritm of dpkg was incompatible with iphone, so i simply did a backup of my installed dpkg-deb with

`mv /usr/local/bin/dpkg-deb /usr/local/bin/dpkg-deb.bak`

and I copied the dpkg-deb locate in

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/
```

in the folder where was my installed dpkg.deb with

```
sudo cp /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/dpkg-deb /usr/local/bin/dpkg-deb
```

Now it works.